# How can I get log right when using two OWIN authenticationOptions at the same time?

Tags: c#, owin

My web frontend has apis that accept two kinds of tokens. In order to authenticate, I setup app's ConfigAuth method like below. Then at controller layer, for each api, i use AuthorizationFileterAttribtue to ensure right token is expected. This works. However, it has a problem when coming to logging. Whenever a token arrives, both below authentications will run. Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated is set to true if any of the two authentications passes. For example, if a token is valid for WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions, JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions will fail. So no matter what, I always get one failed log. Do you know how I can deal with this situation and make sure no failure log is written when token is valid?

```
        app.UseAadBearerAuthentication(
            new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Tenant = ...,
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ...
                }
            });

        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
            new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ...
                },
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to add a middleware after the authentication providers are done and check if the user is authenticated there

```
app.UseAadBearerAuthentication(...);
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(...);
app.Use(async (env, next) =>
{
    if (env.Authentication.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        // Add log
    }
    await next();
});
```